# replacing a string in all file in perl in windows

Tags: regex, windows, perl

I want to replace a string with another string in all the files in windows.
All files with same extension.
I tried with following perl one liner command but it seems "*" is not working for windows.

```
perl.exe -pi.bak -e "s/Hello/ABCD/ge" C:\Users\Jamimb\Desktop\Test\*.tmp
```

So please help.

Comment: I suspect the equivalent works in Linux because the command interpreter shell expands any filename with a * to a list of the actual filenames, before the program is executed.  It may not work in Windows because this wildcard expansion of the * does not occur.

Comment: @Paul:Any other way instead of * in windows?

Comment: The perl might behave better if run from cygwin or some other shell instead of the usual dos command line.  http://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: Before trying that, check and see if your perl will modify individual files.  If it won't modify individual files that you name, there's no point fixing the *.

Comment: @Paul: *"Behave like Linux"* is not a synonym for *"Behave better"*. There are many good things about Linux, but having any parameter that looks like a file glob expanded for you before you can look at it isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can expand the command line parameter explicitly from within Perl using `glob`.

Also, the `/e` ("eval") modifier on the substitution is wrong in this instance. If `strict` were in place it would cause a *Bareword not allowed* error, but without it it is simply a no-op as `ABCD` evaluates as `'ABCD'`.

Try this

```
perl -i.bak -pe "BEGIN{@ARGV = map glob, @ARGV} s/Hello/ABCD/g" C:\Users\Jamimb\Desktop\Test\*.tmp
```

Comment: Thank you very much..The above applies to the files which are in same directory. Is there any way to replace the string in files of sub directory?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean. It will use whatever directory is specified in the command-line parameter. It will also expand several wildcarded expressions if you pass more than one parameter, like `perl ... path1/*.tmp path1/subdir/*.tmp`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (perhaps):

```
for %f in (C:\Users\Jamimb\Desktop\Test\*.tmp) do perl.exe -pi.bak -e "s/Hello/ABCD/g" %f
```